# Only show print statements on console & don't show any INFO in Python logging

Tags: python-3.x, logging, python-logging

I have configured my logging to log both File & Stream.

I just want to see the print statements in my console & see other info on my log file (except unhandled `exception`s as python shows them on the console by default)

I set the `StreamLogging.setLevel(level=logging.CRITICAL)` but it still shows API connection messages.

I want to get the Python's default `stderr` like before configuring the logging, but also change the output, like adding `%(asctime)s` before printing.

###### My Logging

```py
import logging

FileLoggingFormat = f"%(message)s"
FileLoggingDate = r"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S"

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

logger = logging.getLogger()

# Add StreamHandler
StreamLogging = logging.StreamHandler()
logger.addHandler(StreamLogging)
StreamLogging.setFormatter(logging.Formatter("%(message)s"))
StreamLogging.setLevel(level=logging.CRITICAL)

# Add FileHandler
FileLogging = logging.FileHandler(
    filename="Log.log",
    mode="w",
    encoding="utf-8"
)
logger.addHandler(FileLogging)
FileLogging.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(FileLoggingFormat, FileLoggingDate))
```

###### ❌ Not suitable Result in Console

(Printed statements showed by )

```bash
 Port: 1523
 NotFound.
INFO:library.connection.connection:Connecting...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\test.py", line 20, in <module>
    f.write(message)
TypeError: write() argument must be str
INFO:library.session.session:Session stopped
Session stopped
```

###### ✅ Suitable Result in Console

(Only display prints & unhandled exceptions)

```bash
 Port: 1523
 NotFound.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\test.py", line 20, in <module>
    f.write(message)
TypeError: write() argument must be str
```

###### ✅ Suitable Result in Console

(Only display prints & unhandled exceptions **with date**, added `%(asctime)s` to StreamHandler)

```bash
2022/10/22 10:16:03.678
 Port: 1523
2022/10/22 10:16:03.700
 NotFound.
2022/10/22 10:16:03.706
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\test.py", line 20, in <module>
    f.write(message)
TypeError: write() argument must be str
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several things that need explaining:

#### Using `logging.basicConfig`

You use `logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)`. That has for effect to create a `StreamHandler` and attach it to the root logger (the one you are using since `logger = getLogger()` and `getLogger()` with no argument returns the "root" logger).

At the end of your logging setup, if you do:

```py
print(logger, logger.handlers)
```

It will give:

```
<RootLogger root (INFO)> [<StreamHandler <stderr> (NOTSET)>, <StreamHandler <stderr> (CRITICAL)>, <FileHandler /home/vvvvv/Log.log (NOTSET)>]
```

You have 2 `StreamHandler` instead of just 1. Moreover, the superfluous `StreamHandler` has a logging level of `NOTSET` meaning it will log everything. This is the cause of your bug.

You could solve it by removing this line:

```py
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
```

Doing so, gives

```
<RootLogger root (INFO)> [<StreamHandler <stderr> (CRITICAL)>, <FileHandler /home/vvvvv/Log.log (NOTSET)>]
```

#### Using a child logger instead of the root logger

As previously said, you are using the root logger (`logger = logging.getLogger()`). You should refrain from doing so and instead use a child logger, like this:

```py
# logger = logging.getLogger()
logger = logging.getLogger("foobar")
logger.propagate = False
```

Set `propagate` to `False` to avoid sending the logs upwards to the root logger.

Piecing everything together gives the correct behavior:

```py
import logging

FileLoggingFormat = f"%(message)s"
FileLoggingDate = r"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S"

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

logger = logging.getLogger("foobar")
logger.propagate = False

# Add StreamHandler
StreamLogging = logging.StreamHandler()
StreamLogging.setFormatter(logging.Formatter("%(message)s"))
StreamLogging.setLevel(level=logging.CRITICAL)
logger.addHandler(StreamLogging)

# Add FileHandler
FileLogging = logging.FileHandler(
    filename="Log.log",
    mode="w",
    encoding="utf-8"
)
logger.addHandler(FileLogging)
FileLogging.setFormatter(
    logging.Formatter(FileLoggingFormat, FileLoggingDate)
)
```